# Function-backed Action can't seem to apply change involving Geohash/Geopoint - Object Type expects a String

Tags: typescript, palantir-foundry

TL;DR: My function-backed Action that attempts to assign a GeoPoint to a Geohash property fails with an error that seems to say it was expecting a string.

I have an Object Type with a String property that has been set as a Geohash in the property editor. The field in the backing dataset contains strings representing lat,long pairs, formatted like '12.123456,34.345678'.

I then have a function-backed action to edit Objects of that Object type. It's currently set up to take a string as input (with the regex `^-?[0-8]?\d\.\d+,-?1?[0-7]?\d\.\d+$` used as Submission Criteria to ensure it matches the expected lat,long format). The Typescript function then assigns it to the Object Type as a GeoPoint like:

```
@Edits(myObjectType)
@OntologyEditFunction()
public editMyObjectType(
    myObject: myObjectType,
    .....
    latlong?: string,
    .....
): void (

    .....

    let geopoint = latlong? GeoPoint.fromString(latlong) : undefined;

    .....

    const cols: Partial<myObjectType> = {
        .....
        coordinate: geopoint
        .....
    }

    Object.assign(myObject, cols);
}
```

This raises no errors. The tooltip when I hover on `coordinate` in the `cols` variable shows that, based on the imported Object Type of which it is an instance, it expects a value of type `GeoPoint | undefined`. `GeoPoint.fromString(latlong)`, where `latlong` is a string, obviously stores a GeoPoint in `geopoint` (when not undefined).

In the frontend, though, when I try to submit the Action I get this error:

```
Failed to apply change.

Error: [Actions] PropertyTypeDoesNotMatch
Error ID: <a UUID>
Related values:

 - propertyTypeRid: Optional[ri.ontology.main.property.<another UUID>]
 - expectedType: Optional[ValueType{value: PrimitiveWrapper{value: STRING}}]
 - actualType: Optional[Value{value: GeohashWrapper{value: 12.123456,34.345678}}]
```

That value at the end, `12.123456,34.345678`, always matches whatever I put into the latlong field in question.

It appears as though the Object Type is expecting to receive a string from the function here, despite that in the Typescript editor it expects a GeoPoint and shows an error if I try to pass it a string. What gives?

**Edit**: Also the function appears to work fine when testing from the Live Preview in the Typescript editor, returning an Object with e.g. `coordinate: 12.123456,34.345678`.

**Edit 2**: I see that a GeoPoint is not simply a lat,long string, but a struct containing a separate lat and long value. This only begs the question: in Typescript, why does it see the `coordinate` property of `myObject` as a GeoPoint in the first place? Why can I not assign it a string?

Comment: I got your code to run without issues on a simple object type with properties: id (string), name (string) and location (geohash). I don't think there's an error in your code, including with the type signatures. Things I would double check: (1) that the property type is indeed a geohash and that there isn't any indexing issues for that object type; (2) that the Action form fields are the correct types; (3) that you're able to create a no-code Action that accomplishes the same change you're trying to do with the function-backed Action. In other words, I suspect the code is a red herring.

Comment: It appears the indexing did in fact fail, and I'd completely missed it. I'll take a look at that and add any relevant information I find, solution or no. Thank you for coming to my aid again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got your code to run without issues on a simple object type with properties: id (string), name (string) and location (geohash). I don't think there's an error in your code, including with the type signatures. Things I would double check

1. that the property type is indeed a geohash and that there isn't any indexing issues for that object type
2. that the Action form fields are the correct types
3. that you're able to create a no-code Action that accomplishes the same change you're trying to do with the function-backed Action.

In other words, I suspect the code is a red herring.